# WinJS Listview prevent drag and drop on specific element only

Tags: drag-and-drop, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a ListView in my WinJS app that uses the built in drag and drop functionality to allow users to reorder pages in a document.

Is there a way to prevent some elements within that ListView, in this case the first item, from being dragged?

I am using WinJS 4.1

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found the answer,

```
var firstItem = listView.getElementsByClassName('win-itembox')[0];
firstItem.draggable = false;
```